# How to update row value if a different column has specific set of characters within string in r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a column in a df that has a long string of characters. I need to update a different column when a certain part of the string matches a set. For example:

```
Folder <- c("Computer-A-BC-12-3","Computer-A-DC-45-6","Computer-A-BC-12-3")
Location <- c("NA","NA","NA")
df <-data.frame(Folder, Location)
```

I want to update the location to 56.32 only for the Folder which contain "A-BC-12-3". So far I tried

```
df$Location[df$Folder %>% str_subset(pattern = "A-BC-12-3")] <- "56.32"
```

but only get this error message:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Location, value = c("NA", "NA", "NA",  :
replacement has 4 rows, data has 3

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do realize that "NA" is not an R `NA` I do hope. I suspect @Park failed to consider that possibility the you might be a new R user and you  need to understand that his answer was assuming you wanted that column to be character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
df$Location[df$Folder %in% (df$Folder %>% str_subset(pattern = "A-BC-12-3"))] <- "56.32" 

              Folder Location
1 Computer-A-BC-12-3    56.32
2 Computer-A-DC-45-6       NA
3 Computer-A-BC-12-3    56.32
```

Or using `grepl`

```
df$Location[grepl("A-BC-12-3", df$Folder)] <- "56.32"
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks so much!